# Using Maven being a Proxy/VPN, Maven not downloading any files

Tags: eclipse, maven, proxy

I have been trying to set up Maven for automated testing for the past few days. I am using eclipes IDE with m2e installed. I do NOT have an external standalone Maven installed on my PC. Every time I try to create a new Maven project, it fails with the following message:

```
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6.
```

I check and see that a .m2 file was created under users/my_name/.m2. When checking all of the files, they are all appended with .lastUpdated. I added my own settings.xml file to the .m2 folder. I have currently not added any proxy settings in the xml file.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                  https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository/>
  <interactiveMode/>
  <offline/>
  <pluginGroups/>
  <servers/>
  <mirrors/>
  <proxies>
  </proxies>
  <profiles/>
  <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

I believe that because I am currently behind a corporate proxy/vpn, it is preventing maven from installing any of the files, hence all of the dependencies being missing.

I have looked into internet options > lan settings., but Proxy Server is not selected. When accessing http://amibehindaproxy.com/ -it says I am being a proxy.

My question is, how do I find the values I need to put into my  tags for the settings.xml file. I do not know how to find values for:

```
<id>myproxy</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
  <port>80</port>
  <username>proxyuser</username>
  <password>somepassword</password>
  <nonProxyHosts></nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

Again, most of the suggestions here are telling me to check my internet options> lan settings but there is no info there because the "Proxy Server" checkbox is not checked. I have no clue where to find ,,. I think the only thing I know is the  because It shows in the http://amibehindaproxy.com/ browser. I am very new to proxies/configuration topics so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are in a company, why not ask the admin for the proxy details?

Comment: I actually just finished talking to the admin and after discussion, I realized that it is an automatic proxy: http://wpad/ ....  . However, I am not sure where that falls into the maven settings file.

Comment: So can the admin give you proxy details? If you cannot get through, you may need to set up a Nexus/Artifactory server with special rights that proxies Maven Central (this is often done in companies).